# Google Map Autocomplete of Undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm developing a mobile app with Ionic 4 (Angular 8) framework. After installing AGM - Angular Google Map I tried to make a map working. It works with no problem. Now I'm updating this map with Autocomplete Place by Google API.

**Error recieved:** *Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined*

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { AgmCoreModule, MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'MY API KEY',
      language: 'it',
      libraries: ['geometry', 'places']
    }),

/.../
```

**update.module.ts**

```js
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
import { } from "google-maps";

/.../

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'MY API KEY',
      language: 'it',
      libraries: ['geometry', 'places']
    }),

  ],
  declarations: [UpdatePage, UpdateComponent],
  exports: [AgmCoreModule]
})
```

**update.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
/.../
import { AgmCoreModule, MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
import { } from "google-maps";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-update-component',
  templateUrl: './update.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update.component.scss'],
})
export class UpdateComponent implements OnInit {


  @ViewChild('googleAutocomplete') public searchElement: ElementRef;


  /.../


          this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
            let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(searchElement.ElementRef);
            autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
              this.ngZone.run(() => {
                let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
                if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null){
                  return;
                };
              }
              );
            });
          });
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

**update.component.html**

```html
        <ion-input #googleAutocomplete formControlName="googleAutocomplete" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" type="text" required></ion-input>
```

Comment: Are you still having this issue? Can you please provide a codesandbox or stackblitz so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?